# map with IO in haskell?

Tags: haskell

Hi I need help with the map function and IO operations in haskell.

I have a List like `[(x,(y,z))]` and i want to give a function each item of the list, so i want to use `map` the problem is, that the function looks like:

```
test :: (String, (String, String)) -> IO (String, String, (String, String))
test (a,(b,c)) = do
    -- some IO stuff
    return (a,b, (c,c))
```

but when i try to use map (`map test myList`) i get a error because it is `IO`, how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try to use `mapM` (from `Control.Monad`) instead?

(sorry, without more code I can only guess)

Answer (score 3):

Because `test` resides in the `IO` monad you'll have to use `mapM` see [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Control-Monad.html#v%3AmapM), [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_IO_for_Imperative_Programmers) and [here](http://members.chello.nl/hjgtuyl/tourdemonad.html) for details.

Comment: That second link is great. I never found that before.